# Which branch of VS Code GitHub repo should I start with?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

In VS Code's git remote repository [VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode), there are so many branches.

Can I know what do these branches do?

To contribute, test development, to VS Code, which branch should I checkout and start with?

Answer (score 2):

There is a separate documentation on [`How to contribute to VSCODE`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute)

From [DOCS](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute)

> Even if you have push rights on the Microsoft/vscode repository, you
>   should create a personal fork and create feature branches there when
>   you need them. This keeps the main repository clean and your personal
>   workflow cruft out of sight.

Comment: it means i should create new branch from master branch, is that correct?

Comment: Yes from the master branch